# Text alignment in JTextPane, same as ms office

Tags: java, swing, text, fonts, alignment

this is really frustrating i made text alignment, using JTextPane, at the moment it's working in one of my application. But i'm trying to use it with different class it's not working even now its not working at the same class, it did work once, when i closed my netBeans, and reopen it, it's not working  now at all...

## NOTE: if you know how to make perfect the jtextpane please the code down...

```
  public void getTing_alignment(){
  box.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
      //in this class i have put this code, i use this class for color, 
     // font, and 
    //text alignment     
            if ((e.getStateChange() != ItemEvent.SELECTED) || box.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
                area.requestFocusInWindow();
                return;
            } else {
                area.getText();
                String alignmentStr = (String) e.getItem();
                int newAlignment = box.getSelectedIndex() - 1;
         
            
                box.setAction(new AlignmentAction(alignmentStr, newAlignment));
                box.getSelectedItem(); // initialize to (default) select
                area.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        }
    }
    );
}//end 


     Font_Color ali = new Font_Color();
     ali.setArea(MainTextPanel);
     ali.getTing_alignment();//this is the main class, which i invoked
```

Comment: This posted code tells me nothing about your application. I have no idea what you are trying to do with this code. I have no idea what kind of alignment you are attempting to do. I suggest you take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html). It shows you how to use `Actions` from the editor kit to style the text. Their are "alignment" Actions in the StyledEditorKit that you can use to align text to the left/center/right.

Comment: Thanks for responding, this code basically change the text alignment, center, right and left.  have a look in this project. http://www.javaquizplayer.com/examples/text-editor-using-java-example.html. this code worked for me once perfectly

Comment: `this code worked for me once perfectly` - then compare the working code to the current code to see what the difference is. Actually the better approach is to start over with a simple example that contains a JFrame and a JTextPane and 3 buttons (or menu items) to allgn the text. The point is to simplify the code so you can see exactly what you are doing. Then if it doesn't work you has a small (20-30) line program to post. Then maybe we can look to see what you are doing.

Comment: This is base on JComboBox, it did work for me too, once but it is not working now, im wonder about this now. will you post all your code here ?

Comment: Do you have any idea about ms office text alignment?

Comment: I don't have any code. If you want help then post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problems. I gave you a link to the Swing tutorial that shows you how to use the Actions defined in the editor kit.

Comment: Okay my Complete Code:   String labels[] = {"Text Align", "Left", "Center", "Right", "Justified"};
    DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(labels);
    JComboBox box = new JComboBox(model); // and the rest is at my post

Comment: //------------------------this is how i invoke the method//                                                               
     Font_Color fontt = new Font_Color();
     fontt.getTing_alignment();
     fontt.setArea(MainTextPanel);

Comment: well i have made another simple project, that is working perfect, i copy and paste all the code from new project on my main project but its not working hahhah, sorry i'm new i cannot join chat group,

Comment: well  i have solved this problem, i was using box.setEditable (true) that is why i did not work

Comment: The above code is perfectly working guys, i have an error, not error its an logic error, box.setEditable(true); then its not working, make sure do not use box.setEditable(true);